# How can I perfectly forward arguments to a STL collection?

Tags: c++, performance, stl

How can I perfectly forward arguments for the creation of objects to a STL collection?

I would like to avoid unnecessary copies. While I can avoid this by storing pointers, I do not want to use dynamic memory.

```
struct MyFatClass
{
    explicit MyFatClass(int a) {...}
    ...
}; 

std::vector<MyFatClass> records;
records.emplace_back(MyFatClass(1000)); // How can I avoid this temporary object?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't actually need to create a temporary when using `std::vector::emplace_back`, that's exactly what `emplace_back` is used for:

```
records.emplace_back(1000);
```

This will construct a `MyFatClass` object in-place, avoiding temporaries and extra copies.